# Проблема с админкой wordpress

Tags: wordpress

После переноса сайта на другой домен все работает, но появилась небольшая проблема с админкой. Когда наводишь на какой-либо пункт слева не всплывают подпункты. Увидеть их можно только после нажатия на родительский пункт. На скринах видно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было взять папку wp-includes из чистого wp и заменить ее на хостинге. После этого все заработало